# Truffle dry-run on Ethereum Main reports different gas cost (less) than actual deployment gas

Tags: truffle, gas, truffle-migration

Just wanted to ask about something weird that I keep running into:

I've been deploying smart contracts on Ethereum through `truffle`, and the estimated deployment cost during the `--dry-run (simulation)` is always different than the actual, live, non-dry-run deployment.

**Anybody know why that is, out of curiosity?**
Gas units used seems to be different between the simulation and the actual live deployment.

For example, for the same compiled contract, here's the results of my latest one:

```bash
Migrations dry-run (simulation)
===============================
> Network name:    'ethereum_live-fork'
> Network id:      1
> Block gas limit: 30000000 (0x1c9c380)

2_deploy_contracts.js
=====================

   Deploying 'MyContract'
   ---------------------
   > block number:        13587948
   > block timestamp:     1636539921
   > account:             0x0123
   > balance:             1.106993597391617736
   > gas used:            3721437 (0x38c8dd)
   > gas price:           100 gwei
   > value sent:          0 ETH
   > total cost:          0.3721437 ETH

Contract deployed at address: 0x0456
   -------------------------------------
   > Total cost:           0.3721437 ETH


Summary
=======
> Total deployments:   1
> Final cost:          0.3721437 ETH
```

And the actual deployment:

```bash
Starting migrations...
======================
> Network name:    'ethereum_live'
> Network id:      1
> Block gas limit: 29983726 (0x1c983ee)

2_deploy_contracts.js
=====================

   Deploying 'MyContract'
   ---------------------
   > transaction hash:    0xaAaBbB
   > Blocks: 7            Seconds: 112
   > contract address:    0x456
   > block number:        13587983
   > block timestamp:     1636540178
   > account:             0x123
   > balance:             1.065583597391617736
   > gas used:            4135537 (0x3f1a71)
   > gas price:           100 gwei
   > value sent:          0 ETH
   > total cost:          0.4135537 ETH

   Pausing for 3 confirmations...
   ------------------------------
   > confirmation number: 1 (block: 13587985)
   > confirmation number: 2 (block: 13587986)
   > confirmation number: 4 (block: 13587988)
   > Saving artifacts
   -------------------------------------
   > Total cost:           0.4135537 ETH


Summary
=======
> Total deployments:   1
> Final cost:          0.4135537 ETH
```

The difference of **0.04141 ETH** is non-negligible.
`evmVersion` in my `truffle_config.js` is `petersburg`.

Comment: Well, gas prices can fluctuate during the day (By A LOT). Might that be it?

Comment: @sky both the dry run and the actual deployment transaction are broadcast at `gas_price: 100 gwei`. The difference lies in the different `gas_limit` supplied during the simulation and the live deployment, which truffle for some reason does - and I'd like to find out why :)